# Too few arguments to function App\Awe\JsonUtility::addNewProduct(),

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

i am trying to create a CRUD app and am having trouble, if anyone can point me in the right direction i would be grateful, thank you.

Hi there i am having difficulty using data from the json.

i have used it here and it as worked

```
class JsonUtility
{
    public static function makeProductArray(string $file) {
    $string = file_get_contents($file);

    $productsJson = json_decode($string, true);

    $products = [];
    foreach ($productsJson as $product) {
        switch($product['type']) {
            case "cd":
                $cdproduct = new CdProduct($product['id'],$product['title'],  $product['firstname'],
                    $product['mainname'],$product['price'], $product['playlength']);
                $products[] = $cdproduct;
                break;
            case "book":
                $bookproduct = new BookProduct($product['id'],$product['title'],  $product['firstname'],
                    $product['mainname'],$product['price'], $product['numpages']);
                $products[]=$bookproduct;
                break;
        }
    }
    return $products;
}
```

this is my controller

```
public function index()
{
    // create a list.
    $products = JsonUtility::makeProductArray('products.json');
    return view('products', ['products'=>$products]);
}
```

this is my route

```
Route::get('/product' , [ProductController::class, 'index'] );
```

how can i use this on my controller and what route should i set up to create a product

```
public static function addNewProduct(string $file, string $producttype, string $title, string    $fname, string $sname, float $price, int $pages)
{
    $string = file_get_contents($file);

    $productsJson = json_decode($string, true);

    $ids = [];
    foreach ($productsJson as $product) {
         $ids[] = $product['id'];
    }
    rsort($ids);
    $newId = $ids[0] + 1;

    $products = [];
    foreach ($productsJson as $product) {
        $products[] = $product;
    }

    $newProduct = [];
    $newProduct['id'] = $newId;
    $newProduct['type'] = $producttype;
    $newProduct['title'] = $title;
    $newProduct['firstname'] = $fname;
    $newProduct['mainname'] = $sname;
    $newProduct['price'] = $price;

    if($producttype=='cd') $newProduct['playlength'] = $pages;
    if($producttype=='book') $newProduct['numpages'] = $pages;

    $products[] = $newProduct;

    $json = json_encode($products);
    if(file_put_contents($file, $json))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

This is where i am trying to type to code into.

```
public function create()
{
    //show a view to create a new resource
    $products = JsonUtility::addNewProduct('products.json');
    return view('products', ['products'=>$newProduct], );
}
```

Comment: please share the code where you use the method addNewProduct

Comment: i am trying to use this add new product method, this is where i am confused. do i enter it into my controller and then create a view? thanks

Comment: The create route is for showing a view where you can create an (in this case) product. If you really want to store it/add it to your database there is an `store` function for that. See the laravel controller documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller

Comment: im trying to get a crud view of this, would i not pass this data to my controller?

Comment: how do i insert this:      $newProduct = [];
        $newProduct['id'] = $newId;
        $newProduct['type'] = $producttype;
        $newProduct['title'] = $title;
        $newProduct['firstname'] = $fname;
        $newProduct['mainname'] = $sname;
        $newProduct['price'] = $price; as an array

Answer (score 0):

your function `addNewProduct()` is expecting 7 parameters when called.

you are getting this error because you cannot provide those parameters that your function is looking for.

in your code above you are passing `'products.json'` which is in a string format.

lets assume that it is a JSON data. it will still fail because you are only passing 1 parameter to a function that is expecting 7 parameters.

what you could probably do is change it to

```
public static function addNewProduct($data)
{
     // code here
}
```

then you can pass your JSON data and then go through each of your json using a loop.

Comment: how would i pass those through using a loop, can you take a look at my JSON file and help? i appreciate it. im a beginner lol

Comment: you dont pass it through a loop. you pass it as a single parameter and then decode the json data and use a loop to access each of the data that your json contains

Comment: okay how do i do this, do you have any links on how i can do this, any articles?

Comment: for JSON understanding, you can refer to this: https://beginnersbook.com/2015/04/json-tutorial/

to understand how php functions and arguments work: https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/php-function